# Openshift: no tag for image stream

Tags: openshift

I'm trying to create a simple NodeJS application with Openshift. I have the following Image Streams loaded:

```
$ oc get is -n openshift
NAME         DOCKER REPO                            TAGS                      UPDATED
jenkins      172.30.1.1:5000/openshift/jenkins      1,2                       
mariadb      172.30.1.1:5000/openshift/mariadb      10.1                      
mongodb      172.30.1.1:5000/openshift/mongodb      2.6,2.4,3.2               
mysql        172.30.1.1:5000/openshift/mysql        5.5,5.6                   
nodejs       172.30.1.1:5000/openshift/nodejs       0.10,4
```

Now if I try to create an application using nodejs stream:

```
$ oc new-app https://github.com/openshift/nodejs-ex --name=nodejs-basic 
error: no tags found on matching image stream: "openshift/nodejs"

The image stream "openshift/nodejs" exists, but it has no tags.
```

Why ? to me it appears nodejs has indeed a tag. How can I sort out this issue?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After flushing iptables (iptables -F) and restarting the cluster it seems to work.

Comment: too bad that I dont have this option :(

Answer (score 0):

I had to wait until my OpenShift build finished running and the image had a tag on it.

For example, I do

`oc new-build --strategy=docker --name=app-name --binary=true`

then

`oc start-build app-name --from-dir=./directory-with-dockerfile`

then I need to wait until the build has finished before I run

`oc new-app --image-stream=app-name`